# c program static_assert() char bit=16

Tags: c, static-assert

What is `CHAR_BIT==16` means in this code? It doesn't compile, I can not figure out the reason and what will be in puts so code will compile?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <assert.h>
    static_assert(CHAR_BIT==16,"16 bit falsely assumed");
    int main()
    {
        puts("hello world this");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` tells you how many bits in a byte.

Comment: If you found `static_assert(CHAR_BIT==16, ...);` in some code, there should be some hints as to _why_ that check is done somewhere close to where you found that assertion.

Comment: @TedLyngmo False.  See 7.2p1 of C11.

Comment: @dbush Yey! `_Static_assert` (and `static_assert` via a macro in `assert.h` I suppose)  - Wow, that made my day. I've wanted that many times but just assumed ... stoopid me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CHAR_BIT` is a Macro defined in `limits.h`. It mentions the number of bits in a `char`. Most systems use 8 bits, but there are architectures with less (7 bits) or more.

In your code, the assert is checking, if the system is using 16 bits for a `char`, then only the code will compile.

Note: Based on your compiler version and support, you may need to use `_Static_assert` instead.

Comment: There are no C implementations that conform to the C standard where `CHAR_BIT` is 7. C 2018 5.2.4.2.1 1 requires it be at least 8.

Comment: @EricPostpischil agree, what I meant is there are systems with bytes using 7 bits (not necessarily conforming).

Answer (score 2):

`CHAR_BIT` is defined in `<limits.h>`. You need to include it for your code to compile.

Comment: ...but even then `CHAR_BIT` is *hugely* unlikely to be 16. If it is, I would love to hear about the OP's platform.